# My Java Tortoise and Hare Applet will not run

Tags: java, applet

I am trying to create/simulate a tortoise vs. hare race.  A random number generator is used to make the competitors move....the possible moves being :a distance of 3 squares right, 1 square right, 6 squares left, 9 squares right, 1 square right, 12 squares left, 2 squares left, fall asleep.  The course is plotted with 50 squares of positions with each player having their own respective lanes and starting at position 1.  My problems is that the applet compiles, but does not run when I try to open the html file in the browser.  Am I on the right track?  How do I get this to run....and when it runs, properly?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class Project2 extends Applet
{ 
    Image tortoise, hare;
    int tortX = 250, hareX = 250;
    final int tortY = 100, hareY = 300, WIDTH = 15, HEIGHT = 50;
int turn; String turnNum;
int move; String tMove, hMove;
public void init()
{
    tortoise = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "images/tortoise.gif" );
    hare = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "images/hare.gif" );
    move = 0; turn = 0;
}
public void control()
{
    while (( tortX < 985 ) || ( hareX < 985 ))
    {
        move = (int)(10 * Math.random());
        switch (move)
        {
            case 1:
            case 2:
                tortX += (3 * WIDTH);
                hareX += (9 * WIDTH);
                tMove = "Fast Plod"; hMove = "Big Hop";
                break;
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
                tortX += (3 * WIDTH);
                hareX += WIDTH;
                tMove = "Fast Plod"; hMove = "Small Hop";
                break;
            case 6:
                tortX += WIDTH;
                if (hareX == 250) {} // Agit Nihil 
                else if (hareX <= (250 + (11 * WIDTH)))
                    hareX = 250;
                else
                    hareX -= (12 * WIDTH);
                tMove = "Slow Plod"; hMove = "Big Slip";
                break;
            case 7:
            case 8:
                tortX += (1 * WIDTH);
                if (hareX == 250) {} // Agit Nihil
                else if (hareX <= (250 + (WIDTH)))
                    hareX = 250;
                else
                    hareX -= (2 * WIDTH);
                tMove = "Slow Plod"; hMove = "Small Slip";
                break;
            case 9:
            case 10:
                if (tortX == 250) {} // Agit nihil
                else if (tortX <= (250 + (5 * WIDTH)))
                    tortX = 250;
                else
                    tortX -= (6 * WIDTH);
                tMove = "Slip"; hMove = "Fall Asleep.";
                break;
                // Cuniculus dormit, agit nihil .
        }
        turn++; turnNum = (turn + "");
        repaint();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            delay();
        }
    }
    tortX = 985; hareX = 985;
    repaint();
}
public void paint( Graphics screen )
{
    drawRace(screen);
    if (tortX >= 985)
    {
        screen.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 48));
        screen.drawString("Tortoise Wins", 650, 240);
        clearCurrent(screen);
        fillNext(screen);
    }
    else if (hareX >= 985)
    {
        screen.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 48));
        screen.drawString("Tortoise Wins", 650, 240);
        clearCurrent(screen);
        fillNext(screen);
    }
    else
    {      
        screen.drawString(("Turn " + turnNum), 621, 55);
        screen.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 12));
        screen.drawString(tMove, 59, 65); screen.drawString(hMove, 66, 255);
        clearCurrent(screen);
        fillNext(screen);
    }
    stop();
}
public void clearCurrent( Graphics s )
{
    s.clearRect(tortX+1, tortY+1, WIDTH-1, HEIGHT-1);
    s.clearRect(hareX+1, hareY+1, WIDTH-1, HEIGHT-1);
}
public void fillNext( Graphics s )
{
    s.fillRect(tortX+1, tortY+1, WIDTH-1, HEIGHT-1);
    s.fillRect(hareX+1, hareY+1, WIDTH-1, HEIGHT-1);
}
public void drawRace( Graphics s )
{
    // Initium
    s.drawRect(250, 100, 750, 50);
    s.drawRect(250, 300, 750, 50);
    int lineX = 265, lineYi = 100, lineYf = 150;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 98; i++)
    {
        if (lineX == 1000)
        {
            lineX = 265; lineYi = 300; lineYf = 350;
        }
        s.drawLine(lineX, lineYi, lineX, lineYf);
        lineX += 15;
    }
    s.fillRect(tortX+1, tortY+1, WIDTH-1, HEIGHT-1);
    s.fillRect(hareX+1, hareY+1, WIDTH-1, HEIGHT-1);
    s.drawImage(tortoise, 59, 80, this);
    s.drawImage(hare, 66, 271, this);
    s.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 24));
    s.drawString("Race", 250, 55);
}
public void delay()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 90000000; i++)
    {
    }
}
public void stop()
{
}
```

}

Comment: off-topic: You should use `Thread.Sleep(100);` to delay the process... For details see: [Thread.Sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

Comment: Should the switch statement case be 0 to 9 vs 1 to 10?